# UITextField as subview in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, authentication, uitextfield

How can I achieve something that we can see on login view of Skype app?

It looks like a table View to me with UILabel and UITextField inside it as a subview. I've never done something like so I'd like to know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Check the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *startDtLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 25)];
    startDtLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    startDtLbl.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:startDtLbl];

    UITextField *passwordTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 200, 35)];
    passwordTF.tag = 2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:passwordTF];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

You can add the fields like the above.

Comment: I tried these codes already, they didn't work for me. :( Just for the information, I'm creating tableview programmatically.

Comment: I'm going to guess then that you're not telling the tableView where to get it's content from. Do you have lines such as: tableView.delegate = self and tableView.datasource = self? You'll also have to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols